# Underscore(_) and "% "is not working in search - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a search bar which get projects from API and shows them all are works fine but when I search for underscore(_) only  in the search bar nothing returned. It shows only current page.I am using AngularJS 1.2.

I applied `encodeURIComponent()`also in my search text but only underscore is not returning anything. Suppose I search for `____` or only underscore(no other character) it will not return anything.If I put other characters i.e., `__ui` it works fine.
Only underscore is not working, I do not know why?

P.S.- "%" also not working.They are acting like white spaces.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: [Long shot(!)...] If you are using an SQL DB to look for patches, note that `_` is a wildcard like `%`, except that it is interpreted as a single character _anything_ (when you are using a `LIKE` clause).

Comment: @FDavidov I am working on AngularJS only

Comment: Ah.. OK. Just thought.